# C# Datetime ToUniversalTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una función que me llega un Datetime con fecha y hora de un Select de la vista, necesito convertirla en UTC para poder meterla en Dynamics 365 CRM a traves del SDK, el problema es el siguiente:

```
tratamiento.dc_Fecha = data.fecha.Value.ToUniversalTime();
                        //si la fecha es "25/07/2019 18:30" la convierte en "25/07/2019 16:30"
                        //si la fecha es "25/11/2019 18:30" la convierte en "25/07/2019 17:30"
```

Por lo que veo, el "ToUniversalTime" al ser españa y tener el cambio de horario, según la fecha en el Datetime usa el horario de verano o el horario de invierno en vez de utilizar el de la fecha actual del sistema.

¿Alguna sugerencia? por que para poder introducir la fecha en el SDK necesito que sea un DATETIME UTC

Comment: Y por que crees que `ToUniversalTime` está haciendo mal la conversión?

Comment: No creo que este haciendo mal la conversión, pues en verdad, tiene en cuenta la fecha del Datetime y la convierte bien según el horario de **verano/invierno** en España. Pero no es lo que necesito.

Comment: Mira esto a ver si te sirve: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
DateTime dtUTC = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, data.fecha.Value.Hour, data.fecha.Value.Minute, 0).ToUniversalTime();
```

Es decir, obtienes un nuevo `DateTime` con la fecha actual, pero con la hora de tu `DateTime` de entrada, y a eso le aplicas `ToUniversalTime`.

---

De tu comentario se deduce que quieres convertir a UTC tomando en cuenta la fecha actual, pero almacenar la fecha original. Lo único que debes hacer en ese caso es tomar la hora que hemos obtenido en el método anterior, y crear un nuevo `DateTime` con estos datos:

```
DateTime dtUTC = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, data.fecha.Value.Hour, data.fecha.Value.Minute, 0).ToUniversalTime();
tratamiento.dc_Fecha = new DateTime(data.fecha.Value.Year, data.fecha.Value.Month, data.fecha.Value.Day, dtUTC.Hour, dtUTC.Minute, 0)
```

Comment: Perdería la fecha del datetime y necesito ambas cosas UU

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia he editado mi respuesta. Aunque, como te dije antes, no veo mucho sentido a convertir a UTC tomando en cuenta la fecha actual para actualizar en una fecha donde el horario está dos horas desfasado respecto a UTC. Espero que te sirva de todas formas.